# Unable to reset vuetify v-select in loop programatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I am generating v-select in loop, it is working fine.

The only problem I am facing is that as soon as I select some value then some action takes place but after that I am not able to reset the dropdown value to default or the first value.

v-select keep on showing the value I had selected and does not get reset. I want to reset it manually.

For example, if I select "Feedback" in the dropdown then after the function is executed it should reset to "Select"

My code:

```
<v-select v-if="item.actualStatus == 'complete'"
:items="getItems('completeItems')"
label="Select"
outlined
dense
v-on:input="takeAction($event, item)"
></v-select>
```

GetItems function:

```
getItems(type) {
  switch(type) {
    case 'completeItems':
      return this.completeItems
      break;
    }
},
```

CompleteItems in data function

```
completeItems: [
        {text: 'Select',value: ''},
        {text: 'Call Events',value: 'completeCallEvent'},
        {text: 'Feedback',value: 'completeFeedback'},
        {text: 'Listen Audio',value: 'completeListenAudio'},
        {text: 'View Video',value: 'completeViewVideo'}
      ]
```

Takeaction function:

```
takeAction(event,item) {
      switch(event) {
        case 'completeFeedback':
          this.dialogFeedback = true
          this.feedbackCall(item)
          break;
    }
```

Comment: Simply use `v-model` on the `v-select` and when you want to reset - set the bounded variable to NULL.

Comment: Value of v-model is getting reset but dropdown still shows old selected value, kindly note I am generating multiple dropdowns in for loop

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example how to reset the selection.

```js
new Vue({
el:'#app',
vuetify: new Vuetify(),
template: '<v-app><v-main><v-select v-model="selection" :items="completeItems" label="Select" outlined dense /><v-btn @click="selection = null">Reset</v-btn></v-main></v-app>',
data:
{
  selection: null,
  completeItems: [
        {text: 'Select',value: ''},
        {text: 'Call Events',value: 'completeCallEvent'},
        {text: 'Feedback',value: 'completeFeedback'},
        {text: 'Listen Audio',value: 'completeListenAudio'},
        {text: 'View Video',value: 'completeViewVideo'}
      ],
}
});
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```